# Can't validate iOS app (getting already has valid certificate)

Tags: ios, validation, app-store, certificate

When switching to Yosemite I did a clean install of my Mac and now I'm having issues submitting my iOS to the store.

When I validate my archive I keep getting "Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate".

I have tried renaming and redownloading my certificate from the member center but that didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

A very common "doh!" is you copied over the relevant item in Keychain,

BUT!

you forgot the private key part:

[image]

So fi the disclosure triangle on the left is missing and the "key" symbol part is missing, that's what's happened.

Solution: just EXPAND the triangle and highlight BOTH parts, then click export.  move the file to your other Mac and open.

---

**ALSO** -- don't forget, in Xcode you have to literally login these days.

Xcode - Preferences - second tab == Accounts

[image]

It's easy to forget, say, one of your various client's accounts there.

Comment: Do I really need to have my client's account in here? Won't the provisioning profile, his certificate and private key suffice?

Comment: if you're going to **submit** it using that installation of Xcode, yeah, you gotta have the account in there...

Comment: I am having this problem as well, but I don't have access to my old mac. How can I resolve this issue? I see this when I try to validate my app and I need to get an app into the App Store as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Rob, no problem.  Log in to developer.apple, just make a new certificate for yourself. Call it like RobNov2014 or similar so you are clear.  That cert will "work" on the new Mac.  Then go through and change your provisioning profiles to work with THAT NEW cert.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The App Distribution Guide on the Apple Dev site states that this can be a frequent problem if moving from one mac to another (or re-installing in this case). A simple fix would be to export your certificates as a developer profile file from your previous install, but you probably don't have a back up readily available. Try clicking the 'revoke and request' button and see if you can re-download your developer profile file.

Hope this helps,
Will