# IPA file could not save during archive

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a problem in archive during save the ipa file. When I am doing archive then the ipa file could not save.

Here is the image

[image: ipa could not save]

Comment: Go through this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585334/cant-validate-ios-app-getting-already-has-valid-certificate/26585879#26585879

Answer (score 1):

There may be many cases but first check

Xcode>Preferences>Accounts

Select 'View Details' click the small Refresh icon on bottom, this will download your distribution certificates

[image]

Once you have your distribution profile loaded you can export your ipa file

Answer (score 0):

If refreshing the keys does not work, you will want to revoke the certificate and get a new one. I have had to do that multiple times.